# How to search SQL database to prevent duplicated variables

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many

I am trying to create a question and answer website, like quora or stackoverflow. How can I put in a custom method to search if the tagName already exists, so it can just select it, rather than create a duplicate. I already have an idea it should look something like this:

```
var objectExists = _context.Tag.Find(a => a.Name == tag);
if (objectExists == null)
{
   _context.QuestionTag.Add(new QuestionTag(){Tag = new Tag(){ Name = tag });
}
```

But I can't seem to incoporate that logic into the parseTag method

```
 public async Task BuildQuestion(string title, string body, string tags, ApplicationUser user)
            {
                var question = new Question
                {
                    Title = title,
                    Body = body,
                    QuestionTags = ParseTags(tags),
                    User = user
                };
                _context.Add(question);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

    public List<QuestionTag> ParseTags(string tags)
    {
        var tagList = tags.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        var questionTags = new List<QuestionTag>();

        foreach(var tag in tagList)
        {
            questionTags.Add(new QuestionTag()
            {
                Tag = new Tag(){Name = tag}}
            );
        }
        return questionTags;
    }
```

Comment: You just need to write a SELECT query first to check for the existence of a record with the same text. And/Or put in a unique constraint on the field to stop duplicates being created.

Comment: @ADyson (pre-comment-edit when you just spoke about the constraint) presumably because that would cause the `SaveChangesAsync` to do a rollback, making it impossible to save a question; I do strongly agree that it should *have* the constraint - just: if you ever hit the constraint, that indicates an upstream failure

Comment: @ADyson Could you please give me a coding example? Pleeaasee...I've been fighting with this thing all night and I keep getting errors.

Comment: @AllocSystems you already *are* doing a `SELECT` query first to check for the existence ... that's what your `Find` method does, no?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: You can use a GroupBy to get all the duplicates or use the Disinct method.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about only adding the non-existing tags to the database in `ParseTags()`?

```
public List<QuestionTag> ParseTags(string tags)
{
    var tagList = tags.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    var questionTags = new List<QuestionTag>();
    var anyNewTags = false; //to see if we have to SaveChanges()

    foreach(var tag in tagList)
    {
        //You should do the check and add your tags here
        var objectExists = _context.Tag.Find(a => a.Name == tag);
        if (objectExists == null)
        {
           //tag doesn't exist
           //create a new tag, add it to db
           //also add it to the tag list

           var newTag = new QuestionTag() { Tag = new Tag() { Name = tag } };
           _context.QuestionTag.Add(newTag);
           questionTags.Add(newTag);

           //there is a new tag, we have to call SaveChanges()
           anyNewTags = true;
        }
        else
        {
           //tag exists, just grab it, no need to add anything.
           questionTags.Add(objectExists);
        }
    }

    //do we have new tags, do we need to call SaveChanges()?
    if (anyNewTags) _context.SaveChanges();

    return questionTags;
}
```

Comment: That's beautiful bro. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, I'm getting an error on questionTags.Add(objecExists); Something about converting Linq.IQuerable

Comment: I can help if you post more information. What does the exception say?

Comment: Thanks, bro. It says: Cannot convert from **System.Linq.IQueryable<WebAppDATA.Models.Tag> to WebAppDATA.Models.QuestionTag**

Comment: It doesn't make sense since `var objectExists = _context.Tag.Find(a => a.Name == tag);` is supposed to be `WebAppDATA.Models.Tag`, not an IQueryable. We are supposed to add a `Tag` object to `List<Tag>`. Maybe VS is misleading you, can you debug and try to find the IQueryable?

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think of that.